# A dynamically allocated array of integers deletes itself when function ends

Tags: c++, arrays

The function is supposed to read integers from a text file. The first number will tell how many number are there in the input file.

I first initialize the pointer that receives the integers to NULL, but for some reason when the function ends and returns, it's still pointing to NULL.

```
bool readFileToArray(const char* fileName, int *arr, int &size)
{
    ifstream input = ifstream(fileName);
    int i, num;

    // check if file opened successfully and allow only non negative integers to be read as num of elements
    if (!input.is_open() || !(input >> size) || size < 0)
        return wasError(input);

    // allocate an array of 'size' size
    arr = new int[size];

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        input >> num;

        // check for illegal input
        if (input.fail())
            return wasError(input);
        else
            arr[i] = num;
    }

    // given size and actual size mismatch
    if (i != size || !input.eof())
        return wasError(input);

    // if file opening and writing ended successfully
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to return the allocated pointer you need to make `arr` a reference, otherwise you're just leaking a pointer locally.

Change:

```
bool readFileToArray(const char* fileName, int *arr, int &size)
```

to:

```
bool readFileToArray(const char* fileName, int *&arr, int &size)
```

Also consider using more idiomatic C++, such as `std::string` and `std::vector`, rather than C-style `char *` strings and raw arrays/pointers.

Comment: As cynical as it gets, I'm writing this version with a raw array to show how primitive raw arrays are in comparison to STLs

Answer (score 2):

Using `int *arr` passes the pointer to the function by *value*. When you assign to `arr` in the function, you're overwriting a copy of the pointer, not the actual variable you passed in.

Either pass a pointer to a pointer `int** arr` or a reference to a pointer `int*& arr`.